# ObservableCollection not notifying on Add or Delete with Prism

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I am using Prism BindableBase to notify property change events and it works mostly well, except for ObservableCollections. Changes such as Add or Delete are not notified. What could be the issue:

BindableBase that implements INotifyPropertyChanged code is here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Prism.Core/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs_

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _selectedObjects;
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> SelectedObjects
    {
        get => _selectedObjects;
        set
        {
            //This line never called when AddItem
            SetProperty(ref _selectedObjects, value);
            UpdateMyunction();
        }
    }
    
    public MyViewModel(){
        SelectedObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
        AddItem();
    }
    
    private void AddItem(){
        SelectedObjects.Add(new MyObject());
        
        // RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOperators)); // tested with and without, no impact
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course not, as you do not call `SelectedObjects = ...`. You need to subscribe to the [SelectedObjects.CollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged) event to be notified. The usual UI frameworks like WPF etc. do this.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what do you mean. The collection is updated but it is not Notifying  the changes.

Comment: How do you know it does not notify of the changes? Who calls `AddItem` anyway except the constructor (that's at a time where noone can observe the notification)?

Comment: @Haukinger above snippet doesn't excecute UpdateMyunction() because of no notification. However, in debug mode I can see that the  ObservableCollection increased. Pls bear in mind that above is just a small snippet to demonstrate the problemt

Comment: `above snippet doesn't excecute UpdateMyunction() because of no notification` - that's wrong. It's because of not calling the setter. The `UpdateMyunction();` line gets called when you change the value of `SelectedObjects`, i.e. call its setter. It won't be called if you _modify_ `SelectedObjects` by calling, for example, `SelectedObjects.Add`. You want to remove the setter and add `_selectedObjects.CollectionChanged += (_, _) => UpdateMyunction();` to `MyViewModel()`.

Comment: The `CollectionChanged` event of an observable collection is a different event than `PropertyChanged`. You need to the adjust your misconception of the nature of the events that matter in your context. You need to listen to both of them, but you seem to listen to just one currently.

Comment: I you want PropertyChanged  events to be also raised along with CollectionChanged events, which is doable but not necessarily smart, you just have to raise that event whenever you add/delete an item to your collection.
However when you an item to a collection the collection property does not change technically. It only changes when you replace the old collection by a new one or by null.

Comment: @lidqy My understanding was that Prism would handle these trivial situations in the BindableBase, which apparently it doesn't . I have no plans to raise both Collection and Proprerty change events, But merely make the simple add/delete scenario working.

Comment: @Haukinger thank you for the clarifications. I have moved your code into the setter of SelectedObjects and it works, but it looks bit ugly:) I am still not sure about your statement  that .Add is not modifying the value of SelectedObjects as the count of SelectedObjects increases. When I call new collection the setter is called correctly. Is there any other way to force calling setter and make code look more elegant?

Comment: The value of `_selectedObjects` is an instance of an `ObservableCollection<MyObject>` and `PropertyChanged` will be raised for `SelectedObjects` by `SetProperty` if you replace that instance with another instance ("change the value of the property"), if you change something _inside_ the instance, neither `MyViewModel` nor `_selectedObjects` is involved. Also, a setter that does more than a call to `SetProperty` is not ugly, but rather the norm for anything but trivial code.

Comment: you have also a simple typo or copy&paste issue - I think.
Instead of `// RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOperators));` you likely want `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedObjects));`

Comment: As to the CollectionChanged vs PropertyChanged thing. If you have an observable collection 'MyColl' and whenever you add or remove an item to/of it you want to raise PropertyChanged for MyColl you just need to do that explicitly/manually. You dont and never have to raise CollectionChanged for the ObservableColection because its already built-in.
You could do it the way you've done it (without the name-issue) or you could aswell bind and eventhandler to CollectionChange and in that handler raise propertychanged. Depends on whether you do control all situations where items are added or removed.